# updated VM VirtualBox now its looping back to enter password: after entering

Tags: virtualbox, login, password

I updated my Virtualbox to version 6.1.32, when I now try to enter my password the system changes to a black screen, then loops back around to ask me to enter my password again. When I enter the incorrect password, it tells me my password is incorrect. I then reverted to a previous version but still no success.

I've tried ctrl+alt+f1 to enter the terminal and login with the same username and password as the one above but am being told: Login Incorrect

I would be grateful for any help that you can offer, please go easy on me, I'm still new to this coding journey...

Comment: What are the host and guest systems?

Comment: HI Organic Marbles, my computer is running windows 10. virtualbox is Xubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I think i had 2 versions of Ubuntu installed, 22.04 and 20.04. They both took up enough space to not allow me into the disk. I managed to fix the Kernals that weren't fixed on 20.04 in its safe made (22.04 wouldnt let me fix anything.) then used went back in with gparted live to extend the space I reallocated on the drive... its been almost a week, but I fixed it!!

(sorry for the non tech speak, if you cant tell already I'm a newbie to tech.)